# Threejs not appying the texture to cube

Tags: opengl-es, three.js

I am struggling with texture..
see http://jsfiddle.net/henros/e6zs9mcj/3/
Can someone tell me why the color for the cube is not added..
See line 105 - 109

```
        var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50,50,50);
        var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000});
        var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);
        cube2.position.set(-300,0,25)
        scene.add(cube2);
```

Comment: Can you add more information about your question? in order to make better the answers and solve faster the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code defines a fog that seems to interact with the geometry. Disabling the fog or setting the *I-don't-care-about-fog* flag resolves the issue.

```
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, fog: false});
```

Check your scene setup.